# VS Code tasks cannot be found by launch config when they are located in workspace config

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

In tradition, we put `launch.json` and `tasks.json` in `.vscode` folder in order to make debugger works. Meanwhile, VS Code also support developer to put these 2 configurations into workspace by setting them in `*.vscode-workspace`. Here are the steps to reproduce:

1. Create new js project by `npm init` with all default parameters.
2. Create new `index.js` with 1 line of code: `console.log('done');`
3. Create new `ts-sample.code-workspace` file within the same root folder, the content should be like following:

```
{
    "launch": {
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "type": "node",
                "request": "launch",
                "name": "Launch Program",
                "skipFiles": [
                    "<node_internals>/**"
                ],
                "program": "${workspaceFolder}/index.js",
                "preLaunchTask": "nodeversion"
            }
        ]
    },
    "tasks": {
        "version": "2.0.0",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "label": "nodeversion",
                "type": "npm",
                "script": "nodeversion",
            }
        ]
    },
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ]
}
```

4. Open the workspace
5. Open `index.js` and press F5
6. Error dialog prompted our with the following error message: `Could not find the task 'nodeversion'`
7. Open OUTPUT Panel and Error message is shown as following:

```
Error: The npm task detection didn't contribute a task for the following configuration:
{
    "label": "nodeversion",
    "type": "npm",
    "script": "nodeversion"
}
The task will be ignored.
```

**For easy demo please clone the sample project from https://github.com/mannok/WorkspaceLaunchTaskDemo**

Is this a bug of VS Code or something I have missed?

Answer (score 1):

Try saving the workspace first, then running the tasks while ensuring a workspace is loaded.

Comment: Please provide an answer to the question.

Comment: well I already answered it ! you need to Save the Workspace !! sometimes you just need to save the workspace As and override the workspace, exit and start VSCode again.. then it will work